# ITK python take time to load for the first time

Tags: python, itk

I'm using ITK Wrap python, when I use for the first time in my code an ITK function, my code freeze like 30sec and after any other function are really fast.

I have a bunch of numpy computation and after I call :

```
image_type = itk.Image[itk.F, 2]
itk_py_converter = itk.PyBuffer[image_type]
```

Just this can take the 30 seconds. And after I'm using SymmetricEigen and that load instantly. And if I try to reorder or change the first itk function, it always the same thing. And I don't understand why.

My import is only `import itk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading the [documentation](http://farsight-toolkit.org/wiki/FARSIGHT_Tutorials/Quick_Start), I found this :

> Once the command line window appears, type
>
> `import itk`
>
> This may take some seconds while the shared libraries are loaded.

So It normal to take time during the loading.